# Elasticsearch: Get distinct record by a specified field

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search some results by fields and sort them by other field ("myscore"), here is the ES (5.2.2) query:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {"myscore": {"order" :"desc"}}
  ],
  "query": {
    "query_string" : {
       "query" : "(field1:foo) AND (field2:bar)"
    }
  }
}
```

then, I can get this:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 3,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "fooindex",
                "_type": "footype",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "foo",
                    "field2": "bar",
                    "x_id": "x001",
                    "myscore": 0.9
                },
                "sort": [
                    0.9
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "fooindex",
                "_type": "footype",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "foo",
                    "field2": "bar",
                    "x_id": "x001",
                    "myscore": 0.8
                },
                "sort": [
                    0.8
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "fooindex",
                "_type": "footype",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "field1": "foo",
                    "field2": "bar",
                    "x_id": "x002",
                    "myscore": 0.7
                },
                "sort": [
                    0.7
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However, I want to get distinct results according to the field **"x_id"**, like this:

```
{
    "_index": "fooindex",
    "_type": "footype",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
        "field1": "foo",
        "field2": "bar",
        "x_id": "x001",
        "myscore": 0.9
    },
    "sort": [
        0.9
    ]
},
{
    "_index": "fooindex",
    "_type": "footype",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
        "field1": "foo",
        "field2": "bar",
        "x_id": "x002",
        "myscore": 0.7
    },
    "sort": [
        0.7
    ]
}
```

The similar SQL would be "select * from footype group by **x_id**";

I've tried aggregation:

```
"aggs": {
    "unique_xid": {
     "terms": {
       "field": "x_id"
     }
    }
},
```

The result would be:

```
"aggregations": {
   "unique_ids": {
      "buckets": [
         {
            "key": "x001",
            "doc_count": 2
         },
         {
            "key": "x002",
            "doc_count": 1
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The problem is that the aggregation results leak field information and they are sorted by "count" not "myscore". Is there any way to get distinct results by a specified field?

Comment: In your `x001` bucket you realize that there are two documents, right? So which `myscore` should be taken into account for sorting the buckets? The max one?

Comment: @Val Yes, the max one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your buckets might contain more than one document and you want to use the maximum value of `myscore` within those documents in order to sort your buckets, then you can do it like this:

```
"aggs": {
   "unique_xid": {
      "terms": {
         "field": "x_id",
         "order": {
            "score": "desc"
         }
      },
      "aggs": {
         "score": {
            "max": {
               "field": "myscore"
            }
         }
      }
   }
},
```

Comment: No need to add size: 10 since this is the default ;-)

Comment: yes, in my case the size was up to 1000, just let people know how to increase the aggregation size.

Comment: This is mostly what I want, you saved me. Do you have any idea to do chunking on the aggregation result? like the "from" and "size" methods.

Comment: Aggregations don't support pagination, but since ES 5.2 they do support [partitioning](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions)